# Visualforce Command button to Reload and Save Parent Record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have implemented a Visualforce page housed within a section on a standard page layout.  On this page is a CommandButton which is currently performing a page reload of the parent record (via simple Javascript) when the related (child record) is Saved.

I would like to also trigger one additional "Save" of the parent record after the child "Save" button is clicked on the Visualforce section.

Is this possible?  Any help appreciated!

Visualforce (child records):

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveConditions}" rendered=" 
{!conditions.size>0}" 
reRender="pgBlckId,redirectPanel" /> 
                <apex:outputPanel id="redirectPanel" > 
                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!shouldRedirect}"> 
                        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                            window.top.location.href = '{!redirectUrl}'; 
                        </script> 
                    </apex:outputText> 
                </apex:outputPanel>
```

Apex Class:

```
    public pageReference saveConditions(){

    try {
        shouldRedirect = true; 
        redirectUrl = stdController.view().getUrl(); 

        List<Pricing_Condition__c> temp = new List<Pricing_Condition__c>();
        for(ConditionWrapper A : Conditions) temp.add(A.Condition); 
        upsert temp;

    //}catch(dmlException E){ ApexPages.addMessage(new 
    ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage())); }  
    } catch (DMLException ex){

    shouldRedirect = false; 
    redirectUrl ='';

    String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
    Integer occurence;
    if (ex.getMessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION')){
    occurence = errorMessage.indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,') + 
    34;
    errorMessage = errorMessage.mid(occurence, errorMessage.length());
    occurence = errorMessage.lastIndexOf(':');
    errorMessage = errorMessage.mid(0, occurence);
    }
    else {
                errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
                }
```

Comment: Where in here are you attempting to save the parent record?  What isn't working?

Comment: The parent page is reloading properly per my code snippet but I would like to add the functionality of also re-saving any updates made the parent record at the same time the child record(s) is saved.

Comment: Is `temp` the instance of parent object ? And what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Pleas edit your original post to include more code and details on how is the VF page allowing edits both the parent and child records.

Comment: There is not much to it, @David Cheng.  After the Command Button is clicked, the "savecondition" method triggers the parent page reload.  I would like to initiate a Save of any edits made to the parent record after the page is reloaded.  Let me know if any other info/screenshots are needed.